# How to make url id parameter like a path

Tags: javascript, php, html, .htaccess

so I've got a problem. I want to make this URL
`https://example.com/l/click.php?id=something` 
to look like this 
`https://example.com/l/something`

Does anyone know how to make it happen per code?

I tried editing & using this sample .htaccess code but it didnt worked :/

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?users/(.*?)/?$ /users.php?name=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /users\.php\?name=([^\&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^/?users\.php$ /users/%1? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Hint: `RewriteRule ^1/([\w-]+) click.php?id=$1`

Comment: @devpro and this will work?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^l/([^/]*)$ /l/click.php?id=$1 [L]`

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Still not working :/

Comment: try it... it just a hint

Comment: @devpro not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I tested some .htaccess code and made my solution.
It's pretty simple and works the best way it could!

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ click.php?id=$1 [L]
```

If you want to use it on your own just change the `click.php` to your own PHP file

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement **rewriteRule** in your **.htaccess** file in the directory where your php files resides.

Something like create a file called **.htaccess** and save the code below in it

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ click.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ click.php?id=$1
```

On your php you will have something like

```
<a href = "click/$id'></a>
```

or

```
<a href = "/$id'></a>
```

Always remember to shut down **apache** and restart it for it to take effect